# Visual Studio Code file filter behavior

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've opened a folder in vscode and have a fairly a large file structure to navigate. It would be very helpful if I were able to filter across those files in a way that showed only the file names that containe the filter string while still showing their location in the file hierarchy. I could have sworn that I've done that before but now have lost it.

We do have highlighting in the Explorer pane, by selecting the explorer pane and starting to type. The difficulties there are that it:

- Highlights files but doesn't eliminate unmatched files
- Doesn't expand folders that contain the matched files
- Does a confounding search that is the equivalent of putting a wildcard between each character typed

Do extensions exist that do all of the following?

- Filter the file names based on search string (i.e., hides the unmatched files)
- Expand the folders that contain the matched file names
- Allows for exact search (or regular expression)